# Is there an uncensored version with head shown in the bag?

Tags: school-days

Spoilers for School Days anime.

I've seen versions of the ending where we see or don't see Sekai's explicitly stabbing Makoto. There's exactly 1 video I've found where we see [Makoto's head in the bag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKsJunlsgFk). Is this legit, i.e. there really is an uncensored version that shows this? Or just an edit?

I'm asking I've seen versions where we see that Sekai explicitly stabs Makoto, but we don't see head in the bag, so I think it's an edit.

Comment: I at least remember the head in a bag part from watching it around 2007. That and the boat. Which was nice.